# sending faxes over sip with t38modem and hylafax

Tags: sip, fax, modem

I would like to send (and not to receive) faxes. AFAIK, t38modem + hylafax should work fine.

After configuring hylafax to look for ttxT38-1,ttxT38-2,ttxT38-3, I'm running the following:

```
# t38modem --no-h323 -u T38modem --sip-no-listen --ptty +/dev/ttyT38-1,+/dev/ttyT38-2,+/dev/ttyT38-3 --sip-proxy account:password@ekiga.net --sip-register account@ekiga.net,password --stun stun.ekiga.net --route "modem:.*=sip:<dn>@sip.diamondcard.us"
```

then in another console

```
# service hylafax-restart
$ sendfax -d 3628123456 test.pdf
```

The t38modem console writes

```
Call[df4b04f442] from modem:T38Modem%20v1.2.0 to sip:3628123456@sip.diamondcard.us, no route!
Call[df4b04f442] from modem:T38Modem%20v1.2.0 to 3628123456@+/dev/ttyT38-2, no route!
Call[df4b04f442] cleared
```

faxstat shows the ttyT38 to be working (Initializing server, Waiting for modem to come ready, Running and idle are the three states that vary.), but the job status reflects the t38modem output:

```
JID  Pri S  Owner Number       Pages Dials     TTS Status
7    126 S myuser 3628123456  0:5   1:12   13:52 No local dialtone
```

Could someone help me out in getting a *local dialtone*?

Comment: Are you using the config file example that comes with t38modem (at least the source code, the Debian package seems to have removed it) (`config.ttyx` from the HylaFax subdirectory of the t38modem source code)